# How to delete 0KB text file

Tags: c#

1) I am new to c sharp,

I am having a problem ,

I know how to delete the file,

I am using this line of code to delete the file,

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         File.Delete(a);
    }
```

I want to know how to delete 0KB file.

2)and one more thing i want to know how many path we can save for our application like ,

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            String a = (String)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP");
    }
```

I think there are more paths like Application.StartupPath ,can anyone pls say how many ways are there to save a path like Application.StartupPath .

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me,

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: In your second example, why do you need the cast?

Comment: Based on your comments you'll want to update your question to say that you want to delete all 0 length files in a folder.

Answer (score 3):

1. You delete a 0KB file just like you delete any other file (i.e., `File.Delete` is correct). If the file cannot be deleted, it is probably in use. You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out which process is using the file.
2. Other special paths can be obtained using [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) with the [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration.

---

**EDIT** (after reading the comments): If you want to delete *all* 0-length files in the directory, you can

- use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to get a list of all the files in the directory,
- use [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) to get the size of the files, and then
- use [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) to remove certain files.

In fact, the [MSDN page on FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) contains an example that outputs a list of files and their sizes in a given directory. You should be able to adapt this example to delete all files with 0 length.

Comment: i just a gave a example that i cam delete a file i want to delete a zero kb file can u pls say me how to delete

Comment: @GBasha: Your example is already the solution. Just replace `string Path` with a string containing the path to the zero kb file.

Comment: there are many file contained in the path i want to delete just 0kb file which doesnot have any text in it

Comment: Looks like he wants to delete all 0kb files... not a specific 0kb file.

Comment: @GBasha, @Ranhiru: Ah, thanks, it's more clear now. I've extended my answer.

Comment: @G Basha - People shouldn't be _guessing_. You should explain better in your question. Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

In regards to you first question - you delete a 0 length file the same way you do any other file:

```
File.Delete(pathTo0LengthFile);
```

Your second question doesn't make sense. You can save your file in any path on the drive that the account the application runs under has write permissions to.

There are several system and special folders that you can get the path of use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783871.aspx) - perhaps that's what you mean.

Comment: no i just gace a example for u that i can delete a file i want to know how to delete a 0kb file

Comment: @G Basha - You do it the same way.